# Evaluate paragraph in cider

Tags: elisp, clojure, cider

I'm new to Emacs (after 10+ years of Vim) and want to use it primarily for clojure.

Coming from Lighttable, one thing I absolute liked was the way it evaluated just the right sections of code no matter where I am. This is basically: Evaluating a paragraph surrounding the cursor position. Some examples (`||` represents the cursor, `$FROM ... TO$` represents what I'd like to have evaluated):

```
(comment

$FROM
(my-func ||[:test :one])
(xy)TO$

$FROM
(defn [y]
  (let [x y]
    (println|| "xy")))
)TO$

)
```

So basically I want to evaluate the paragraph (Note: Not necessarily a top level form since I surround them in `(comment)`). I have no knowledge of Elisp. I tried this as an effort.

```
(defun my-cider-eval-paragraph ()
  (interactive )
  (safe-excursion
     (mark-paragraph)
     (command-execute 'cider-eval-region)))
```

<strike>But I'm clearly making many mistakes.</strike> Edit: Actually, my example works if I just change `safe-excursion` to `save-excursion`. Funny, I actually think both spellings makes sense.

Thanks for reading.

Comment: Does `cider-eval-defun-at-point` not do what you want?

Comment: I dont do clojure and can't test this. but I looked at the source for `cider-eval-region` and perhaps this will work: `(cider-eval-region (save-excursion (backward-paragraph) (point)) (save-excursion (forward-paragraph) (point))` instead of using command-execute and mark-paragraph, the source of cider-eval-region is very simple, so it may be a problem with the region. What exactly goes wrong with your example?

Comment: @Dan: No this doesn't do what I want. I want it independent of defn's. @Jordon Biondo: Yes, this seems to do exactly what I wanted. I just realized I'd like the result actually "pprint"ed but cider does not offer a `pprint-region` which I guess makes sense since a region might contain multiple forms. If you submit it as an answer (and possibly note why mine doesnt work) I'll accept the answer.

Comment: Actually, I just realized I made a very silly mistake and misspelt "save-excursion". My example then does work. Sorry for the noise.

Comment: @Vanessa: could you post your own correction as an answer and accept it?  That will mark this question as answered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although this is not pristine elisp, the following should work.

```
(defun my-cider-eval-paragraph ()
  (interactive) 
  (save-excursion
    (mark-paragraph) 
    (command-execute 'cider-eval-region)))
```

Note this is exactly what you wrote, except the macro is called saVe-excursion.

Answer (score 1):

[lispy](https://github.com/abo-abo/lispy) provides a vi-like experience for LISP dialects, including Clojure.
It integrates with CIDER.

You can eval the current Clojure expression with <kbd>e</kbd>.
For instance, starting with this code, with point represented by `|`, and CIDER already running:

```
|(defn sqr [x]
  (* x x))

(filter odd? (map sqr [1 2 3 4 5]))
```

- <kbd>e</kbd>: `#'user/sqr`
- <kbd>je</kbd>: `(1 9 25)`
- <kbd>fe</kbd>: `(1 4 9 16 25)`
- <kbd>fe</kbd>: `[1 2 3 4 5]`
- <kbd>he</kbd>: `(1 4 9 16 25)`
- <kbd>he</kbd>: `(1 9 25)`
- <kbd>ke</kbd>: `#'user/sqr`

If you want to implement something on your own instead, look at `lispy`'s [le-clojure](https://github.com/abo-abo/lispy/blob/master/le-clojure.el).
It's around 100 lines of CIDER integration, but the important stuff for you is something like:

```
(let* ((str (buffer-substring-no-properties
             (region-beginning)
             (region-end)))
       (res (nrepl-sync-request:eval str))
       (val (nrepl-dict-get res "value")))
  (message "result: %s" val))
```